# squareroot, newton and recursion problems in python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to program something to approximate a number's square root using newton's algorithm, but while it woks for numbers which root are an integer, it simply fails with everything else. I get runtime errors every time I try to compute the square of say 2.25 or 3 or whatever. How do I solve this?

```
n = float(input("Which number's square root would you want to compute?  "))

def oldguess():
    root = n /2
    return root

def newguess():
    root = 0.5 * (oldguess() + n / oldguess())
    if root**2 == n:
        print root
        return root
    else:
        newguess()


newguess()
```

Comment: That's not how recursion works, you keep using the `oldguess`...

Comment: thats also not really newtons method ...  I think that only works where the root is also only 1/2 of the N .... ie it only works for 4

Answer (score 0):

because of how floating point numbers works 1.23**2 will never equal what you want... you need to check with a threshold

```
threshold = 1e-5
if abs(root**2 - n) < threshold :
```

but that does not seem to be newtons method ... here is how you should implement it according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number

really you should be comparing previous guess to current guess (or next to current) ... since it always converges to a solution it will continue to get closer to the solution with each iteration (rapidly, ie difference between previous guess and current guess will rapidly approach zero) ....

so I would implement it something like this

```
import random
def newton_squareroot(target,guess=None):
    if guess is None:
        guess = random.randint(1,int(target))
    threshold = 1e-5
    next_guess =  guess - (guess**2-target)/float(2*guess)
    if  abs(guess-next_guess)< threshold:
        return next_guess
    return newton_squareroot( target,next_guess)



print newton_squareroot(2.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a hard coded threshold as @Joran-Beasly suggests, it is preferable to keep the loop going until the approximation fails to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You're method is not really *recursive*, recursive means that you call the same method within a method and *reuse* it's result, or pass attributes so that the next call works with the previous one. In your method:

```
def newguess():
    root = 0.5 * (oldguess() + n / oldguess()) #oldguess remains the same, so nothing incremental, every guess will be as bad as the previous one
    if root**2 == n:
        print root
        return root
    else:
        newguess()
```

You call `oldguess()` so every call to `newguess()` will be exactly the same: there is no "*incremental behavior*".

What you can do is start with a simple guess - pass this for instance as an attribute, and then keep improving the guess:

```
def newguess(guess,n):
    threshold = 1e-5
    root = 0.5 * (guess + n / guess)
    if abs(root**2-n) < threshold:
        return root
    else:
        return newguess(root,n) #reuse the previous guess and return

print newguess(oldguess(n),n)
```

With the tolerance mechanism as described by @JoranBeasley.

And one better uses parameters for `oldguess` as well:

```
def oldguess(n):
    root = n /2
    return root
```

Using global variables in general is a bad idea, the same for methods that `print` results, *I/O* like `input` and `print` should not be handled by utility methods.

So the full code reads:

```
def oldguess(n):
    root = n /2
    return root

def newguess(guess,n) :
    threshold = 1e-5
    root = 0.5 * (guess + n / guess)
    if abs(root**2 - n) < threshold :
        return root
    else :
        return newguess(root,n) #reuse the previous guess

n = float(input("Which number's square root would you want to compute?  "  ))
print(newguess(oldguess(n),n))
```